# can't running a project in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in android development,I tried to run this project on adnroid emulator but I get this error:

[image]

so please how can I solve the error,I have imported all workspace projects,I work with android studio
thanks for help

Comment: It says "correct the above warnings first" so scroll that window up, read the warnings, and correct them.

Comment: the error said:Warning:com.ofss.fcdb.mobile.android.qr.DecodeHandler: can't find referenced class com.ofss.fcdb.mobile.android.rms.logger.Flog

Comment: There are 12 warnings according to the gradle build output, that's one of them.  Fix them all.  That one is pretty obvious -- you're missing that class.  You need to install it before the code will compile.

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply I will install it